# Java read line above

Tags: java

I need to save numbers which are generating randomly by this code.

```
import com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal.generic.GOTO;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

import static java.lang.System.exit;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int chose;
        int[] card = new int[9];
        int[] pin_save = new int[4];
        System.out.println("1. Create an account");
        System.out.println("2. Log into account");
        System.out.println("0. Exit");

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        chose = scanner.nextInt();

        switch (chose) {
            case 1:
                //generate card

                System.out.println("Your card has been created");
                System.out.print("Your card number is:" + System.lineSeparator() + "400000");
                Random random = new Random();


                for (int i = 0; i < card.length; i++) {
                    int n = random.nextInt(10);
    //                    for (int a = 0; a < card.length; a++){
    //                        card[a] = n;
    //                    }
                    System.out.print(n);
                }

                //System.out.println("400000" + java.util.Arrays.toString(card));
                System.out.println(System.lineSeparator() + "Your card PIN:");

                for (int j = 0; j < pin_save.length; j++) {
                    int pin = random.nextInt(10);
                    for (int p = 0; p < pin_save.length; p++) {
                        pin_save[p] = pin;
                    }
                    System.out.print(pin);
                    //System.out.println(pin_save);
                }
                break;

            case 2:
                //login
                System.out.println("Your card number is: ");
                System.out.print("400000" + card);
                System.out.println("Your PIN is: ");
                System.out.print(pin_save);
                break;
            case 0:
                System.out.println("Bye!");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Example output is:

```
Your card has been created
Your card number is:
4000008273821792
Your card PIN:
4826
```

What should I use to save card number and PIN? 400000 is constant so what I really need is the second part. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking? Do you have to encode the data? Are you asking what kind of file (like .txt, .dat, .whatever) you should use or are you asking how to write into any files with Java? Or are you asking about databases?

Comment: It is a console aplication so it prints all in console. I need to save it however but i dont't know how to do it clearly and comfortibly withought using any databases outside the app.

Comment: `clearly and comfortably` is debatable. I'd argue that there are a lot of people who consider using databases to be very clear and comfortable. There are a lot of pros and cons for every way of saving and as it stands, I would consider this question a bit too broad and ***very*** opinion-based. What exact problem did you stumble over when researching how to save data with java? Why didn't searching for `How to write data into a file with java?` solve your question for you? What is it that was missing there that we can help with?

Comment: right above your line ```Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);``` typ ```String number = ""``` Then, underneath ```int n = random.nextInt(10);``` you typ ```number = number.concat("" + n);``` Now, once your loop is completed you have "saved" your number in a String-variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store them into an **`String`**, for example:

```
  String lastCardNumbers="";

  for (int i = 0; i < card.length; i++) 
  {
      int n = random.nextInt(10);
      lastCardNumbers+=n;
      System.out.print(n);
  }
```

The variable `lastCardNumbers` will store the last digits, as it casts the values and appends them to the string.
And your system out should look like

```
System.out.print("400000" + lastCardNumbers);
```

Or you can avoid casting and store them into an **`array`**:

```
  int[] lastCardNumbers = new int[card.length];

  for (int i = 0; i < card.length; i++) 
  {
      lastCardNumbers[i]= random.nextInt(10);
      System.out.print(lastCardNumbers[i]);
  }
```